# Using Microsoft client side validation with Content Security Policy

Tags: asp.net-core, safari, content-security-policy

I'm trying to use Microsoft's client side validation along with a Content Security Policy

In my ASP Net Core (v3.1) razor view I have the following:

```
<div asp-validation-summary="All" class="text-danger"></div>
```

When the page is first rendered, I get a list item with no text, just the red dot.

The HTML has been changed by the client side validation javascript (jquery-validation):

```
<div class="text-danger validation-summary-valid" data-valmsg-summary="true">
    <ul>
        <li style="display:none"></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

My Content Security Policy (CSP) prevents inline styles, so the inline style display:none doesn't work, hence the red dot.

I discovered unsafe-hashes and changed my CSP to:

```
style-src 'self' 'unsafe-hashes' 'sha256-aqNNdDLnnrDOnTNdkJpYlAxKVJtLt9CtFLklmInuUAE=';
```

Unfortunately although this works in Chrome, Firefox and Edge, it doesn't work in Safari on my iPhone (iOS 14.5) or my Mac Mini (v11.2.3)

Can anyone suggest a fix for Safari, or perhaps how to change the Microsoft client side validation to not use the inline style?

Answer (score 1):

> Can anyone suggest a fix for Safari

Safari does [not support 'unsafe-hashes'](https://csplite.com/csp/test296/#bug_Safari_unsafe-hashes) nor for `style-src` nor for `script-src`. Currently there is only one way of use 'unsafe-hashes':

style-src 'unsafe-inline'; style-src-attr 'unsafe-hashes' 'sha256-aqNNdDLnnrDOnTNdkJpYlAxKVJtLt9CtFLklmInuUAE=';

Chrome will follow style-src-attr directive, other browsers (Safari/Firefox/Edge) do not support it and will use 'unsafe-inline' from the 'style-src'.

> how to change the Microsoft client side validation to not use the inline style?

The `style="display:none"` is added by jQuery-validator via `.attr()` method, which internally calls the `setAttribute("style", ...)`. CSP counts `setAttribute(style)` calls as inline style, while `element.style.property = 'prop_value'` is [not treated](https://csplite.com/csp146/#style-prop) as inline style.
Therefore the task is ro change `setAttribute("style")` calls to the set of equivalent `element.style.property` calls.

jQuery has a special [plugin](https://github.com/jonathanKingston/jQuery-csp-inline-style-fix) to fix inline styles by replacing `.attr()` method to a safe `el.style.property` calls.
Alternatively you can fix any JS library by use a rough [hack](https://csplite.com/csp/test343/) working the same way.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed answer. I tried the jQuery plugin and the hack but neither of them worked here

Comment: Could you switch off javascript in browser and check the presence of `style="display:none"` in the HTML? Looks like it's inserted on the server side.

Answer (score 1):

This is a known issue. [aspnetcore/issues/43714](https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/issues/43714)
The Tag Helper asp-validation-summary="All" renders this:

```
<div class="text-danger validation-summary-valid" data-valmsg-summary="true">
    <ul>
       <li style="display:none"> @*CSP problem*@
       </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Workaround: Use the Tag helper only when there is something to display.

```
@if (ViewData.ModelState.ErrorCount > 0)
{
    <div asp-validation-summary="All" class="text-danger"></div>
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggested workaround. I tried it, but it didn't work. Sadly as this validation is working client side, if there are no errors when the page is initially rendered, no errors will be shown until the page is re-rendered by the server.
The good new is that the latest version of Safari on my iPhone (v15.7) doesn't show the red dot, whereas Safari on an older iPhone (v12.5.6) does still show the red dot, so this will be less of a problem going forward

Answer (score -1):

I needed to update a 10 year old website to improve security. I wasn't involved in the creation of the site and it makes extensive use of mvc validation so I needed a feather light solution...even if it is a little hacky.

Removed the inline styles from the html being returned:

```
    public static MvcHtmlString ValidationSummaryCSP( this HtmlHelper htmlHelper,  bool excludePropertyErrors = false)
    {
        var mvcHtmlString = htmlHelper.ValidationSummary(excludePropertyErrors);

        if (mvcHtmlString == null) return mvcHtmlString; 

        var retVal = new Regex("style=\"[^\"]*\"").Replace(mvcHtmlString.ToHtmlString(), "");
        return MvcHtmlString.Create(retVal);
     }
```